# Can anyone suggest an alternative to these similar JPanel constructors?

Tags: java, swing

I have a main `JFrame` that contains many panels. In this `JFrame` there are methods and variables that every panel needs to be able to access, so I have been passing the frame itself into the constructors of all of them like this.

```
pnlLogin = new LoginPanel(this);
pnlMainMenu = new MainMenuPanel(this);
pnlSalesMenu = new SalesMenuPanel(this);
pnlPaymentMenu = new PaymentMenuPanel(this);
pnlAddCash = new AddCashPanel(this);
pnlAddCredit = new AddCreditPanel(this);
pnlAddCheck = new AddCheckPanel(this);
pnlSaleComplete = new SaleCompletePanel(this);
pnlProductMenu = new ProductMenuPanel(this);
pnlAddProd = new AddProdPanel(this);
pnlUpdateProd = new UpdateProdPanel(this);
pnlEmployeeMenu = new EmployeeMenuPanel(this);
pnlAddEmp = new AddEmpPanel(this);
pnlUpdateEmp = new UpdateEmpPanel(this);
```

Then referring to the `JFrame` variables and methods from within the panels like this

```
frmMain.frameMethod();
frmMain.frameVariable = x;
```

I realize that static methods and variables could accomplish something like this and allow me to refer to them in the panels, but that is just not suitable for my applications needs. 
Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this?

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do (it's not abundantly clear to me), you could for your main JFrame, extend JFrame, then create getter methods for each of these items (either by carrying a static instance of them in the class or by looping through all children of the root pane and checking `instanceof` to find the correct panel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right not to use static for that. Though, Swing is pretty awful to code. Best practices are also even more verbose, as you should use singleton pattern for all of your components, so that they're lazily-loaded (best perfs). For example :

```
private JPanel myPanel;

public JPanel getMyPanel() {
    if (myPanel == null) {
        myPanel = new JPanel(this);
    }
    return myPanel;
}
```

This way, you can destroy your panel when you want ot, and be sure you'll get a new one whenever you need it. Also, this component will only be loaded when you need it, and not before (best memory management).

So, to really answer your question, you have not much ways to do it better.

On last thing : be sure to use getter and setter to access other classes variables.

```
frmMain.frameVariable = x;
```

should be

```
frmMain.setFrameVariable(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(...)` or `SwingUtilities.getRoot(x)` method that will return the parent window.

```
JFrame parent= (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
```

where `this` refer to the individual panel.

```
JFrame parent= (JFrame)SwingUtilities.getRoot(panel);
```

Comment: True, but `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this)` will only work for level1 components (those which are in the contentPane). Thus I find this way too random as it's not refactoring proof. The `SwingUtilities.getRoot(panel)` will be more suitable